# Firebase and AngularJS, How to retrieve a value from a firebaseArray

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-retrieval

It seems to be very very simple. But I can't do it.
I just want to get a value of my Firebase DB in my controller.
The Firebase Database is like this:

```
users {
    30549545 {
        name: "Marcelo"
        lastName: "Forclaz"
        years: 24
    }
}
```

In my controller I wrote the following code:

```
app.controller('usersCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('users');
    $scope.userdata = $firebaseArray(ref);
});
```

In the ngRepeat of the HTML code the iteration works fine. But I need to get the "years" value in my controller to use it to another command, ¿How can I do it? I've tried of several deferents ways but I didn't get the wished result. I realized that retrieving data from Firebase width AngularJS is not so easy than make it width simple and pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've got it!

```
$scope.userdata.$ref().once('value', function(snap) {
    angular.forEach(snap.val(), function(index)) {
        console.log(index.years)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until userdata loaded:

```
app.controller('usersCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
var ref = firebase.database().ref('users');
$scope.userdata = $firebaseArray(ref);
$scope.userdata.$loaded()
    .then(function(){
        console.log($scope.userdata);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok. But, how do you get the "years" value now? I wrote your code and the console log returns whole object with the reference data. I only need the years value of him. I tried console.log($scope.data.years) but returns undefined.